# Jenkins scripted pipeline - sh return nonzero exit code but stage SUCCEEDS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins scripted pipeline, I have a build stage that has the following sh command:

```
def buildcmd = "./scriptname.sh"+ <paramters>
def status = sh returnStatus: true, script:"""cd /to/some/dir
eval ${buildcmd}
"""
if(status != 0)
{
   error("Failure")
}
```

After execution, `scriptname` exits with status 2 and `status` variable also contains 2 and the job fails. But however the stage result is shown as `SUCCESS`. I expected both the stage result and build result to be `FAILURE`.

Can anybody please clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

> returnStatus (optional)
>
> Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero
>   status code will cause the step to fail with an exception. If this
>   option is checked, the return value of the step will instead be the
>   status code. You may then compare it to zero, for example.

[Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)

If your goal is to simply let the stage fail use `returnStatus: false`. Unfortunately I can't tell you the difference between a `status code` and `exit code` (like mentioned above). The documentation only tells that if you set `returnStatus: true` the pipeline won't fail on an exit code unequal 0.

You can set the result of the pipeline by yourself ([Source](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline)):

```
if(status != 0)
{
   currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

Comment: I tried setting currentBuild.result also. It will set the result as FAILURE for the entire job, but the stage still SUCCEEDS.

Comment: If you really want to fail the stage simply  do: sh "exit 1"